# Conditional Formating Comparing date between 2 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I need to compare 2 columns say A and B. Both A and B contains dates. If the date in B is less than date in A then I need to colour column B in red colour. I have used this formula `="IF($C$2<$B$2-1)"` But it is not formatting the cells. How can we do the above scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the quotes. As a matter of fact, you don't even need the `IF`. All you have to do is provide a valid formula that returns either true or false.

First clear out any previous attempts at a CF rule that failed. This is no the time to keep something that is broken in the hope that it can be fixed later.

Next select column B then use Home ► Conditional Formatting ► New Rule. Once the **New Formatting Rule** dialog is open, choose *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and supply the following for the *Format values where this formula is true:* text box.

```
=AND($B1<=($A1-1), ROW()>1)    ◄ the date in B is less than the date in A and the row is not the top row
```

Click <kbd>Format</kbd> and select a red *Fill*. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> once to accept the new format then <kbd>OK</kbd> again to create the new rule.

Comment: Is it possible to use the formula, for the condition that the date in B should be less than or equal to one day lesser value on column A? For example if the column A is having value 2nd Jan and Column B is having value 1st Jan then column B should be coloured red else it should be coloured green. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, see my modfied formula above. If you want ti green then either start it as green (the CF rule will override it) or create another CF rule with `=AND($B1>($A1-1), ROW()>1)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF($B2<$A2)
```

You need to get rid of the dollar signs before the row number. Also, it's A and B not B and C.